# how to display data in different view holder in android

Tags: android

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<String> mList;
    private final Context mContext;
    private final OnGalleryItemClickListener mOnGalleryItemClickListener;
    int [] heaightSize = new int[]{1390,1390,1200,1390,1456,1456,1390,1390,1377,1390};


    public GalleryAdapter(List<String> verticalList, Context context, OnGalleryItemClickListener galleryItemClickListener) {
        this.mList = verticalList;
        this.mContext = context;
        mOnGalleryItemClickListener = galleryItemClickListener;
    }

    private int DptoPx(int px){
        return (int) (px/ Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;

        switch (viewType) {
            case 1:
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.main_video_gallery_layout, parent, false);
                return new MainVideoViewHolder(itemView);
            case 2:
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, parent, false);
                return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        int height = DptoPx(heaightSize[position % 9]);
        if (holder instanceof MainVideoViewHolder) {

            try {

                Glide.with(mContext).load((new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + mList.get(position))))
                        .thumbnail(0.1f)
                        .crossFade().override(500,500)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)

                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                        .listener(new RequestListener<File, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                ((MainVideoViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                ((MainVideoViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                return false;
                            }

                        })
                        .into(((MainVideoViewHolder) holder).image_main_video);


            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                // Assume this is a corrupt video file.
            }

            ((MainVideoViewHolder) holder).text_main_video_name.setText(mList.get(position).replace(Constant.FILE_EXTENSION, ""));
            ((MainVideoViewHolder) holder).text_datetime.setText(getFilecreationDate(mList.get(position)));

            ((MainVideoViewHolder) holder).image_main_video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String value = mList.get(position);
                    if (mOnGalleryItemClickListener != null) {
                        mOnGalleryItemClickListener.onGalleryItemClicked(value);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {


            try {

//                ((MyViewHolder) holder).rl_mainlayout.getLayoutParams().height=height;
                Glide.with(mContext).load((new File(mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + mList.get(position))))
                        .thumbnail(0.1f)
                        .crossFade()
                        .override(600, 200)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                        .listener(new RequestListener<File, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                ((MyViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, File model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                ((MyViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                return false;
                            }

                        })
                        .into(((MyViewHolder) holder).image_tumbnail);


            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                // Assume this is a corrupt video file.
            }

            ((MyViewHolder) holder).text_video_name.setText(mList.get(position).replace(Constant.FILE_EXTENSION, ""));
            ((MyViewHolder) holder).text_date_time.setText(getFilecreationDate(mList.get(position)));

            ((MyViewHolder) holder).image_tumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String value = mList.get(position);
                    if (mOnGalleryItemClickListener != null) {
                        mOnGalleryItemClickListener.onGalleryItemClicked(value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mList == null)
            return 0;
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mList != null) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }

    private String getFilecreationDate(String fileName) {
        String filePath = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + fileName;
        File from = new File(filePath);
        if (from.exists()) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            return sdf.format(new Date(from.lastModified()));
        }
        return "";

    }

    public static class MainVideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final TextView text_main_video_name;
        public final TextView text_datetime;
        public final ImageView image_main_video;
        public final ProgressBar progressBar;
        public MainVideoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text_main_video_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_main);
            text_datetime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_datetime);
            image_main_video = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_main_video);
            progressBar=(ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        }
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final TextView text_video_name;
        public final CardView card_containter;
        public final TextView text_date_time;
        public final ProgressBar progressBar;
        private final ImageView image_tumbnail;
        private final LinearLayout rl_mainlayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            text_video_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_video_name);
            card_containter = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.card_container);
            text_date_time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_date_time);
            image_tumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_main_video);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            rl_mainlayout=(LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rl_main_layout);

        }
    }

}
```

this is my adapter class code i am calling like this 
 GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(verticalList,

```
GalleryActivity.this, this);
            GridLayoutManager verticalLayoutmanager
                        = new GridLayoutManager(GalleryActivity.this,2);
            verticalLayoutmanager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {


                    return position == 0 ? 2 : 1;
                }
            });
            rv_videolist.setLayoutManager(verticalLayoutmanager);
            rv_videolist.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
```

i want set 0 position item bigger which is coming correct in below Screen and then i want set position 1 with medium size Item and position 2,3 with smaller Size then 4th position medium size and 5th and 6th smaller size and respectively ..  my current screen is below

[image]

expected screen: expect postion zero should be like below with 2 item in one row:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too long, but below might be the key.

```
 public int getSpanSize(int position) {
     return position == 0 ? 2 : 1;
 }
```

`getSpanSize` should return the size of cell to occupy.
So return `2` at position `0` with grid size `2` means full width, return `1` at other with grid size `2` means half width.

if you want first row have full width and after each row have 3 items with size 2:1:1, your grid size is `4`

```
new GridLayoutManager(GalleryActivity.this, 4);
```

and have SpanSizeLookup respectively. Note that `position` is not column position but position in whole item.

```
 public int getSpanSize(int position) {
     // first item is full width
      position 1, 4, 7... is medium, other will be small
     return position == 0 ? 4 : position % 3 == 1 ? 2 : 1; 
 }
```

I'm not sure i correctly understood your logic, but hope it will be help

Comment: but i want  only two  item in  in position 1 onwards @ytRino

Comment: You mean 2item (half size each) for row 1, and 3items for other rows? then return 2 for position 0 and 1, return 2 for position 2 then return 1 for position 3,4... same way.

Comment: check this image https://pasteboard.co/GGCWWL3.png i want like this @ytRino

Comment: ok so you mean each item has different height and not align top, go for StaggerdGridLayoutManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html

Comment: yes i went through that one also but not able to implement can u please suggest me

Comment: using StaggeredGridLayoutManager how i will set different Size  @ytRino